# Flume : can we create hdfs path(hdfs-sink) dynamically using kafka topics and partitions while using kafka channel

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, flume

I am sending data to kafka topic having multiple partitions.

For example 1 topic with 10 partitions, I want to save data in hdfs path based on the partitions (in multiple hdfs directories).

For Example my hdfs path directories should be like: 
/topicname/partition1,
/topicname/partition2, etc..

I am using Kafka channel - org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel.

Comment: Kafka Connect can do this using Confluent's Default Partitioner

Comment: Okay thank you, but any option to achieve the same using flume?